# Add underline to text with using text-decoration underline - CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

Following is my HTML/CSS code in which I am trying to add a underline below the text without using native `text-decoration: underline` property. But somehow this code is not working. Any pointers what I am doing wrong here

**HTML Code -**

```
<span>
  <a class="test">Add Underline To Text</a>
</span>
```

**CSS Code -**

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.test:hover {
  width: 100%:
}

.test:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -7px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .25s;
}
```

Codepen Link - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEBNyx

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxZBKg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add `width` to `:after` when you hover the `.test` link ? Then you need to write `test:hover:after { }` . Not just `test:hover`.

Even though `:after` is a pseudo-element you must select it if you want to change it's style/s

See below

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.test:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.test:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -7px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .25s;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a class="test">Add Underline To Text</a>
</span>
```